# .NET Core Include Method in Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm not sure if I am asking this question correctly, so please bear with me as this is all very new to me.

I am trying to fully grasp dependency injection in .NET Core while also trying to understand proper design patterns. I found a great tutorial (the teacher is excellent and explains things well), but the problem is that the sample application in the tutorial is being built using Visual Studio 2010 using Unity for Dependency Injection.

I'm trying to convert the DI into my app in VS 2022, but I am not understanding how to include the injection of the methods in the services section of .NET Core.

The example using Unity looks like this:

```
public static ICustomer Create(string TypeCust)
{
     if (custs == null)
     {
         custs = new UnityContainer();
         custs.RegisterType<ICustomer,Customer>("Customer", new InjectionConstructor(new CustomerValidationAll()));
         custs.RegisterType<ICustomer, Lead.("Lead", new InjectionConstructor(new LeadValidation()));
    }

    return custs.Resolve<ICustomer>(TypeCust);
}
```

I know how to include the interfaces and the concrete classes in .NET Core:

```
services.AddScoped<ICustomer, Customer>();
services.AddScoped<ICustomer, Lead>();
```

As requested, here is the rest of the code:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
    string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    decimal BillAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }

    void Validation();
}

public interface IValidation<Any>
{
    void Validate(Any obj);
}

public class CustomerValidationAll : IValidation<ICustomer>
{
    public void Validate(ICustomer obj) 
    {
        if (obj.CustomerName?.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Customer Name is required");
        }

        if (obj.PhoneNumber?.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Phone Number is required");
        }

        if (obj.BillAmount == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Bill Amount is required");
        }

        if (obj.BillDate >= DateTime.Now)
        {
            throw new Exception("Bill date is incorrect");
        }

        if (obj.Address?.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Address is required");
        }
    }
}

public class LeadValidation : IValidation<ICustomer>
{
    public void Validate(ICustomer obj)
    {
        if (obj.CustomerName?.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Customer Name is required");
        }

        if (obj.PhoneNumber?.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Phone Number is required");
        }
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to include the validation methods `CustomerValidationAll()` and `LeadValidation()` that are in the `InjectionContstructor` in the above sample.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you edit the question and add what is `CustomerValidationAll()` and `LeadValidation()`?

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek - I've added the additional code.  Thank you for attempting to help me.  It is truly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you registering `Customer` and `Lead`? They seem data-centric objects containing runtime data? DI might not be a good fit for that. Are you loading their values from the database? Do you possibly need to load multiple different customers within the same request? You might need to take a different approach, such as loading them from a repository. The repository could be registered in the DI Container, but the customer unlikely so.

Comment: Please post the link to the tutorial.

Comment: @Steven Here is the link to the course https://questpond.teachable.com/courses/727112/lectures/13102455

Comment: @Steven - the above code is in Section 2 of the tutorial.

Comment: I'm not very sure about what you want to achieve. [DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0) helps us to inject services so that we pre-define the implement of the interface then using interface in our classes. You had `services.AddScoped<ICustomer, Customer>();services.AddScoped<ICustomer, Lead>();` which already defined 2 implements for the same interface which is impossible now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see the second part of the course, but the learning methodology that the author takes is that he writes code that might have issues and refine later on. In a later video he might very well refine the solution where he registers his *entities* into his DI Container, because in general, this is a very bad practice. It will work for the sample application in the first video, because there is never more than one customer in memory, but this will quickly break down when complexity improves. Keep following the videos; this will likely be explained later on.

Comment: I would also advice to stop trying to convert the code of the presentation into a modern variant. You'll be wasting your time. Keep watching the videos and keep using the old (outdated) Unity framework (for now) until you gained enough knowledge from those videos. The question you have right now might very well be gone when you finished.

Comment: @Steven -thank you very much for the information, and the advice.  I will watch until the end and see if that helps with my understanding.  Your time and guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways you can achieve this, basically, you can create a ServiceResolver or a factory to retrieve your object with a key, or use anti pattern.

You can see more info here: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-keyed-services-dependency-injection-support/